# Undefined local variable or method `profile' for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within my static page home.html.erb, I have a reference to a StaticPagesController. I believe I am doing this correctly, but still getting Undefined local variable or method `profile'.

StaticPagesController

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def profile
        redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
    end 
end
```

home.html.erb

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <% profile %>
<% else %>
    <h1>Welcome to myProjects</h1>
    <%= link_to "Sign up!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Pragash answer is right, but what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `def profile` as helper method, so this method will be available to view. Just add this line below of your `def profile` method:

```
 helper_method :profile
```

You final class will look like this:

```
 class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def profile
      redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
    end 

    helper_method :profile
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you are trying to access a method defined in your controller from the view. I'm sorry but, that is not possible. Using MVC you can't trigger methods in the controller like this. Ideally you should define a helper method under the app/helpers/application_helper.rb or app/helpers/static_pages_helper.rb. Trying to access it the way you are doing would result in the error you see.